# Unhandled exception with ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I get this error :
Unhandled exception at 0x76abc41f in sampleappm.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Magick::ErrorBlob at memory location 0x004cf1c8..
When a i execute the following code :

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Magick::Image image("100x120", "linen");
    image.fillColor("black");
    image.write("test.png");// if i comment this line there is no more error at the execution
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to handle exception, this code worked for me, compiled on VC++2013 64bit.

Here is the output [test.png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20792650/test.png)

Also make sure that you have write permission because ErrorBlob is an IO subsystem error.

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  try { 
    Image image("100x120", "linen");
    image.fillColor("black");
    image.write("test.png");
  } 
  catch( Exception &error_ ) 
    { 
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl; 
      return 1; 
    } 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: i get this error : caught exception : sampleapp.exe UnableToOpenBlob '#FAFAF0F0E6E6' : No such file r directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643

Comment: 'blob' function is used to open streams, files and strings, as possible sources of image data. The error you are getting is because the library is for some reason having trouble locating it's configuration files. Maybe it is missing some environment settings required by the specific installation on your machine. Try to execute inside the installation folder just to test.

Comment: in the ImageMagick directory ?

Comment: Yes, like \ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\sampleapp.exe.

Comment: Maybe if you try to install the libraries again using the install app, not the zip, and with dlls, not static. Try to compile a demo application, like button.cpp (open using Magick++_Demo.dsw) and execute, if it works, just replace the contents of button.cpp with your code and compile again. It worked for me.

Comment: i get a lot of error like this : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: It probably means that you installed the 64bit version and your project is configured to compile for 32bits (default).

Comment: How to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Project properties -> Select Configuration Properties -> Click on Configuration manager button -> On platform dropdown select new -> New platform select X64.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you catch the exception [Exception](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Exception.html) thrown by the Magick implementation, write it to `cout` and try to figure out what has happened:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Magick::Image image("100x120", "linen");
    try {
        image.fillColor("black");
        image.write("test.png"); // this line causes the error
    } catch (const Exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The error you see in your original example only tells you that MS's runtime library cannot handle this exception type.

Comment: i get this error : caught exception : sampleapp.exe UnableToOpenBlob '#FAFAF0F0E6E6' : No such file r directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643

Comment: I got this: Caught exception: Magick: UnableToOpenBlob 'xc:#000000000000': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496